# SQL Server 2014 columns encryption

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, encryption, database-administration

I'm working on SQL server 2014 Enterprise edition and planning to implement encryption to a couple of columns. These columns are referring in ~30 stored procedures.
Not sure which method of encryption I should choose. I considering using column encryption, but from what I've read, this means I should replace these columns to be varbinary and need to modify all related SP. 
Any suggestions for more efficient process?  Is there a way to allow the application (C#) to be able to decrypt the data, or should it be done from the database side on each related stored procedure?

Comment: Much simpler to just put a private key as configurable variable somewhere and encode and decode in your c#. Do you need to be able to run queries on the encrypted columns?

Comment: Do you mean to put the key in the application? If so, I should mention that we have couple of applications which working on the same DB.
Yes, I need to be able to query from these columns a decrypted data.

Comment: Ah,  sorry if you have to query you'd need a SQL to handle it as it would need to decrypt before a where clause could make sense of it.

Comment: what if you create a function in SQL that accepts a parameter and will return an encrypted phrase? use encryptbypassphrase and decryptbypassphrase

Comment: Correct me if 'm wrong, isn't it still means I need to implement this change in every single SP which using these columns (whether selecting or inserting).
I'm less familiar with C# and more into SQL and not sure if there is a better solution which using both.